# Doing a derivative in MatLab

Tags: matlab, calculus

As the title suggests, I am wondering how I can find the derivative of a 'function'.  I am unsure what to do because I really do not have a function defined, just an array of values.  So lets try a simple example:

```
x = 1:5;
y = x.^2
y =
     1     4     9    16    25
```

As expected.  Now I want to take the derivative.  I know that this is 2x.  Possibly use the diff function, as if in symbolic toolkit?

```
diff(y)
ans =
     3     5     7     9
```

This looks like either 2x +// 1, with length length(y)-1.  Is there any way I can compute the derivative of this and get a vector of length(y)?

I do not have the symbolic toolkit.

Comment: Check out symbolic variables in matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html

Comment: What do you expect the derivative of a vector to look like? The function `diff(y)` is giving you a new vector that looks like `y[i+1] - y[i]`.

Comment: @Dan455 I do not have symbolic toolkit.  @AndrewPiliser, I know that diff will give the difference in two conseciutive entries.  I am trying to find another function that will give me `2 4 6 8 10`

Comment: @JamesMaslek So what you want to do is "guess" a function based on a finite set of values? That's not possible.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to find the derivative so I can do this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451063/programming-discrete-fourier-coefficients-in-matlab/451081?noredirect=1#451081

Comment: For a given finite set of values `a` which represent samples of a discrete function _a(n)_, you can approximate its 1st-order derivative with `diff(a)` (and for that matter, the 2nd-order derivative can be approximated with `diff(a, 2)`, and so on...). For this to be accurate you'll need to make sure that sampling rate is sufficient (see the [Nyquist theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little you can do. This topic has already been discussed ad nauseum at the MathWorks web forums.

@noah has provided an example of numerical differentiation (ie: differencing) on a finite data set, whereas you are looking for a means of doing symbolic differentiation of continuous-domain-continuous-range function applied to a discrete-domain data set.

In short, not happening. You're asking how to install a shelf without a hammer, screw driver, or nails. You could always just download and install GNU Octave, a free alternative to MATLAB.

---

References.

1. "Symbolic Math In MATLAB" http://faraday.elec.uow.edu.au/subjects/annual/ECTE313/Symbolic_Maths.pdf
2. "Symbolic differentiation without symbolic math toolbox" http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/83397
3. "GNU Octave - Download" http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/
4. "Symbolic differentiation with GNU Octave" http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Examples-for-use-of-symbolic-toolbox-td1601724.html

Comment: Well that is quite unfortunate.  I kinda figured that would be the case, but I figured I would ask to see if anyone had any input.

Comment: Just install GNU Octave. The syntax is almost identical to MATLAB, and it's free/open-source. It's isn't just a hokey attempt at replicating MATLAB, it's actually a really robust tool often used in universities.

Comment: Please refer to Reference [4] in my post above. There are working examples of exactly what you are attempting to do, using freely available software that works on all modern operating systems. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Numerical differentiation is kind of tricky with small data sets.  The best way I can think of offhand to do this is to explicitly create the function and then apply it to the data.

```
>> syms x y
>> y = x^2;
>> dy = diff(y);
>> dy

ans = 
    2*x

>> v = 1:5;
>> f = matlabFunction(dy);
>> f(v)



ans = 
    2 4 6 8 10
```

Comment: He said he doesn't have the symbolic toolkit.

Comment: But I cannot enter syms

Comment: I also have a large data set, I am just trying to do a quick example

Comment: Sorry, missed the part about not having the symbolic toolkit

Answer (score 0):

You have no symbolic toolbox and you want the symbolic derivative. Here is a suggestion: If you already know the derivative of the function you are trying to apply to your vector (with knowledge of basic calculus), just apply it directly to your vector. For example:

```
vector = [1 2 3 4 5] % intended function = x^2
result = 2*vector
vector = [1 2 3 4 5] % intended function = sin(x)
result = cos(vector)
```

Is there any function you are trying to apply which you don't already know the derivative?